# Crash on std::cout string

Tags: c++, string, crash

I'm getting a crash on runtime when trying to execute a simple program that cout's a string object, i'm using Borland C++ Compiler version 5.5 with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Usaremos as funcoes mais modernas de String em C++
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

// <Prototipos >

int MenuPrincipal(void);

void DesenharCentralizado(string String, int CoordY);

// </Prototipos>

int main() {
    while(MenuPrincipal() != 0); // Para sair, ele deve retornar 0
    return 0;
}

int MenuPrincipal(void) {
    string Titulo = "Agenda";

    clrscr();

    DesenharCentralizado(Titulo, 4);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void DesenharCentralizado(string Frase, int CoordY) {
    int PosX=wherex(), PosY=wherey();

    gotoxy((80-Frase.length())/2, CoordY);
    cout << Frase; // XXX CRASH
    gotoxy(PosX, PosY);
}
```

PS: Please don't complain about using old conio.h and these things, these are for my C++ class and my teacher is teaching us to use it first…

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the `conio.h` stuff?

Comment: I'm sorry your teacher is so weird… this is where up-to-date resources like StackOverflow save the day. … Specifically, if you comment out `gotoxy` before and after the `cout <<`, does it run without crashing?

Comment: Nicol didn't ask ask a complaint, it was because he was wondering if conio might be the problem - if you eliminate possible causes, it aids in determining the cause.

Comment: Actually I need it for clearing the screen and stuff, but i will try. Edit, Doesn't works even completely removing conio.h and it's functions.

Comment: If you make Frase a reference - void DesenharCentralizado(string& Frase, int Coordy) - does it work then? Also generally importing all of namespace std is poor practice, but I doubt that's the cause here

Comment: If you comment out everything in the file and replace it with `#include <iostream>` `int main() { std::cout << "Hello, world!"; }`, does that work?

Comment: @Potatoswatter comment out? psh, get on the #if 0 bandwagon :-P

Comment: ilink32.exe -q -ap -LC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib -LC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib\PSDK c0x32 obj\Release\main.obj ,bin\Release\Agenda.exe,,cw32mt.lib import32.lib ,,
Error: Unresolved external 'DesenharCentralizado(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, int)' referenced from C:\USERS\xx\xxx\xx\OBJ\RELEASE\MAIN.OBJ << If i replace string Frase with string &Frase... and yup, it surely works...

Comment: @OrgnlDave I've mentally promoted that syntax to being a form of comment.

Comment: @wingleader Ah, that was a compile error, not a crash.

Comment: You're not linking with a basic C++ library. I have no idea what it's called with Borland-from-the-year-2000 but there should be no undefined reference to an std::basic_string. That would be like...an undefined reference to an int, or something.

Comment: did you change both the prototype AND the function itself? that's probably the unresolved symbol error with the linker

Comment: At this point why not just printf the string? printf(Frase.c_str()); Then ask your professor for help

Comment: **OOPS**, I really didn't changed the prototype :S So, now it goes back to a runtime error, but at least compiles :o

Comment: anyway, some googling came up with this: http://conio.sourceforge.net/ no idea if it's great or not, but yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borland 5.5. only had *partial support* for `std::string`.

It may well be that your code is to blame in this particular case, but even so, you will not get anywhere (and you will get nowhere very fast) trying to use `std::string` with that compiler.

If your teacher requires you to use Borland 5.5, then your teacher is trying to teach himself or herself as he/she is teaching you. That approach is sometimes OK, but send your teacher here. Now, **to wingleader’s teacher:**

*Borland 5.5 is a broken tool. It is not just pre-standard: it is broken. Students will not learn anything positive from using it, just like trying to learn to play the piano on a piano that is grossly out of tune.*

*If you must support fifteen year old computers (or older), then use maybe g++ 2.95 or Visual C++ 6.0. Otherwise, use free modern tools such as (as of 2012) MinGW g++ 4.6 or newer, or Visual C++ 10.0 or newer. The new compilers (although not the Visual Studio Express IDE) run well even on a computer with just 265 MB RAM, which as of 2012 includes some ten years old PCs. Code::Blocks is a good IDE for old Windows computers.*

Comment: Thanks, I will use MSVC at home, but he -really- forces us to use Borland C++ 3.1. **3.1.** Ugh. So much better next year we will learn ASM (with another teacher) and in the 2014 we'l get into Java...

Answer (score 2):

If you comment out everything in the file and replace it with

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello, world!"; }
```

does that work? If yes, then try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() { std::cout << std::string( "Hello, world!" ); }
```

With the removal of `<conio.h>` and calls to its functions, your program is simple enough to indicate a broken toolchain, and adding features one at a time might help track down what's broken. It could be an incorrect runtime library version, or some kind of corruption in the installation of Borland or the project files.

By re-creating the project one step at a time, either you will track down the cause or you will end up with a working project, at which point you can forget about the problem.

Comment: his compiler is from the year 2000, back when conio.h was meaningful, I think it's probably an internal win32 problem if he's not pre-XP

Comment: std::cout << std::string( "Hello, world!" ); << That won't work. That's the problem. How do I solve it now... Will i have to change compiler? ): Awe, i really hope i can still use Borland C++ )':.

Comment: Update your compiler to the latest version. There's really no downside to that.

Comment: @wingleader Ask your teacher. He should know something about the system if he's dictated its use. In any case, you shouldn't lose points if you can point at why your valid program won't run.

Comment: @chris this compiler is abandonware, he is using the last version.

Comment: I'll venture that there's a linker problem here, as said in comments above it can't find std::basic_string, that would surely cause a crash.

Comment: Is there any other compilers out there that support conio.h? That's really *all* i need.

Comment: @wingleader Try the latest Visual Studio Express. I'm not a Windows programmer, but `conio.h` is a just a Windows support library, and although it's obsolete you should still be able to use it for creating obsolete, 80-column applications.

Comment: @Potatoswatter In the newest conio.h's you can't, it just has basic KB and H/W port in/outs. I'm convinced this is a linking issue though, that std::basic_string not found thing is really odd.

Comment: I don't have a lot of knowledge about that, but doesn't conio.h links to some nananana.lib which is specific to the compiler?

Comment: @OrgnlDave Well, the linker shouldn't be sensitive to `std::cout << std::string()`. I suspect the compiler has fundamentally broken support for passing objects by value, since in that case it should be passing a const reference bound to a temporary. The other problem goes away when he passes by reference instead…

Comment: @Potatoswatter how can it call itself a C++ compiler? it makes me sick... no wonder they abandoned it

Comment: @OrgnlDave Apparently development wound down around the time these things were being standardized and became commonplace. Standard libraries were quite buggy through the early 2000s.

Comment: @Potatoswatter STL was not too buggy during the 2000s...vendor implementations were. I wonder if he could get reference STL to compile...probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Look at my comment, it compiles... I didn't had changed the prototype :S now back to the runtime error.